# "Incognito Away" - No way to hide App, as Advertised?

Tags: applications

I just installed Incognito Away on my cheating husband's Android LG G2, Version 5. I have everything set up but the "Hide App Icon ".  I have two choices at the bottom of the page : Cancel, or Keep Icon Un-Hidden. In other words, I have absolutely no way, apparently, of hiding this icon from my husband. The Google Play Store was very specific that this was a credible and easily performed option within the application. I need help !! ASAP !!

Comment: So you ask us to help you [committing a crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_fraud)?

Comment: You need help but Android support is not the kind of help you need :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Apk editor to change the Icon and disguise it...goodluck